# Why is is_lock_free a member function?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, atomic

What is the reason for why `is_lock_free` requires an instance (it's a member function)? Why not a metafunction of the type, or a static `constexpr` member function?

I am looking for an actual instance of why it is necessary.

Comment: Is it named `is_instance_free`? No. QED.

Comment: It seems it is because of performance [quote from here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2427.html): `The proposal provides lock-free query functions on individual objects rather than whole types to permit unavoidably misaligned atomic variables without penalizing the performance of aligned atomic variables`

Comment: @JesseGood that sounds like an answer. Why is it a comment? ;)

Comment: **C++17** adds [`static constexpr bool std::atomic<T>is_always_lock_free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_always_lock_free), providing a compile-time constant query about a type.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The standard allows a type to be *sometimes* lock-free.

> section 29.4 **Lock-free property**
>
> The ATOMIC_..._LOCK_FREE macros indicate the lock-free property of the
>   corresponding atomic types, with the signed and unsigned variants
>   grouped together. The properties also apply to the corresponding
>   (partial) specializations of the atomic template. A value of 0
>   indicates that the types are never lock-free. **A value of 1 indicates
>   that the types are sometimes lock-free.** A value of 2 indicates that
>   the types are always lock-free.

The [C++ atomic paper n2427](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2427.html#DiscussLockFree) states the reason behind:

> ... The proposal provides run-time lock-free query functions rather
>   than compile-time constants because subsequent implementations of a
>   platform may upgrade locking operations with lock-free operations, so
>   it is common for systems to abstract such facilities behind dynamic
>   libraries, and we wish to leave that possiblility open. Furthermore,
>   we recommend that implementations without hardware atomic support use
>   that technique. ...

And also (as [Jesse Good](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906773/jesse-good) pointed out):

> The proposal provides lock-free query functions on individual objects rather than whole types to permit unavoidably misaligned atomic variables without penalizing the performance of aligned atomic variables

Comment: I've added in the other quote for completeness.

Comment: Sure. That part is also relevant to your question. I missed that.

Comment: I could also imagine an implementation with a fixed number of atomic values or somesuch.